# D3: `bubble.nodes` not applying correct graphical data to dataset

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, bubble-chart

I am trying to create a Bubble Chart using D3 but can't figure out why my data is not processing correctly.  I have imported the processed data from PHP and am now trying to run `bubble.node` in order to apply relevant graphical data for the circles of the chart (radius, x-coord, y coord etc.).  Instead I am currently getting the error:

```
Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="translate(undefined,undefined)"
```

Here's the code (so far; have stopped here because of the error):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // pull data from php file
    var topFrequency = '<?php echo json_encode($frequencyJSON)?>';

    var diameter = 510;

    // create new pack layout
    var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
                   .sort(null)
                   .size([diameter, diameter]);

    // select chart3 div and append svg canvas for graph
    var canvas = d3.select(".chart3").append("svg")
                                     .attr("width", diameter)
                                     .attr("height", diameter)
                                     .append("g");

    jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonData);

    // should return array of nodes associated with data
    // computed position of nodes & graphical data for each node
    var nodes = bubble.nodes(topFrequency);

    var node = canvas.selectAll(".node")
                     .data(nodes)
                     .enter()
                     .append("g")
                     // give nodes a class name for referencing
                     .attr("class", "node")
                     .attr("transform", function (d) {
                         return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                     });
});
```

`topFrequency` looks like this in `console.log`:

```
{"name":"frequencyData",
    "children":[
        {
            "author1":"TUYTTENS, FAM",
            "frequency":7
        },
        {
            "author1":"REVILLA, E",
            "frequency":7
        },
        {
            "author1":"ROPER, TJ",
            "frequency":7
        },
        {
            "author1":"MACDONALD, DW",
            "frequency":6
        },
        {
            "author1":"WOODROFFE, R",
            "frequency":5
        },
        {
            "author1":"CHEESEMAN, CL",
            "frequency":4
        },
        {
            "author1":"GALLAGHER, J",
            "frequency":4
        },
        {
            "author1":"KOWALCZYK, R",
            "frequency":3
        },
        {
            "author1":"HANCOX, M",
            "frequency":3
        },
        {
            "author1":"VIRGOS, E",
            "frequency":3
        }
    ]
}
```

So far as I can tell I'm getting the `undefined` error above because the x and y attributes aren't being created in the array of nodes but I can't figure out why.  Perhaps my data is in an incorrect format?

** EDIT **

Added `JSON.parse(topFrequency)` to get data in correct format.  Now `console.log(jsonData)` gives:

```
Object {name: "frequencyData", children: Array[10]}
children: Array[10]
    0: Object
        author1: "CARTES, JE"
        depth: 1
        frequency: 10
        parent: Object
        r: NaN
        value: 0
        x: NaN
        y: NaN
    1: Object
        author1: "SASSEN, R"
        depth: 1
        frequency: 8
        parent: Object
        r: NaN
        value: 0
        x: NaN
        y: NaN
    2: Object
    3: Object
    4: Object
    5: Object
    6: Object
    7: Object
    8: Object
    9: Object
    length: 10
depth: 0
name: "frequencyData"
r: NaN
value: 0
x: NaN
y: NaN
```

Although this is now returning the correct attributes, it's returning `NaN` for the values.  It is also doing this before I call `bubble.nodes`; I thought these attributes were added by `bubble.nodes`!

Comment: you're missing a closing bracket here .sort(null

Comment: Thanks @tomtomtom, this was just an error in my question not the code, but I have corrected it here

Comment: Have you already tried to console.log(nodes)? my guess is that something is wrong there, where the x and y coordinates should be created

Comment: Yeah, `console.log(nodes)` returned an array of a single object with all the values contained, which is incorrect.  I've now tried using `JSON.parse` on the data and get better results but not yet right (see above edit)

Comment: I suggest you have a look here on how to process the values: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269 because from what I understand the values you're passing are not read so you need to tweak them a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `value` [accessor](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout#value) function for your data:

```
var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d){
    return d.frequency; //<-- frequency is your accessor
  })
  .size([diameter, diameter]);
```

Of course, you also need to append some visual element (like circles) instead of just empty groups.

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/hLk8QGHU1wO6d2kWq0HG?p=preview).

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot, this seems to have done the trick!  Yes, I'm going to continue now and append the circle elements; was just waiting because I knew there was an error.  Thanks for your help.